# Determining home dir of a user

Tags: users, chroot, home

I need to know how home directory for a linux user is determined. Everyone's answer would be "hey, look at `/etc/passwd` and find it out". But this seems not to be always correct. Look at this:

```
$ whoami
test
$ cat /etc/passwd
test:x:2000:2000::/home/test:/bin/bash  (relevant line)
$ echo ~
/root
$ cd
bash: cd: /root: No such file or directory
```

I really have no idea what is going on. It is a subsystem which I entered as root by `chroot --userspec=test path/to/subsystem/ /bin/bash`. Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it so that `~` expands to `/home/test` and `cd` works as expected?

Comment: Related post: [Chrooted user does not start in his home directory and does not load his bash_profiles](https://serverfault.com/questions/438458/chrooted-user-does-not-start-in-his-home-directory-and-does-not-load-his-bash-pr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking up in `/etc/passwd` is correct for local user accounts (unless the system administrator has gone out of their way to make things difficult). The correct general answer is to look up in the user database that contains the user account, e.g. LDAP. Most modern systems use [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) to list user databases, so check [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) on your system if you think there might be non-local accounts.

From an application's perspective, the correct answer is that the home directory is whatever the `HOME` environment variable says.

Login programs (`login`, `sshd`, X display managers, etc.) normally set the `HOME` environment variable to the home directory of the user that's logging in. “High-level” user change programs such as `su` and `sudo` change `HOME` to (with sudo, it depends on the configuration and the command line options). So normally, the definition for “home directory of the current user” matches with the combination of “user's home directory” and “current user”.

But `chroot` doesn't change `HOME`, so your session in the chroot inherits from the `HOME` environment variable in the parent process, which is unsurprisingly `/root`. In bash, like any other shell, `~` expands to the value of `HOME`, defaulting to the user database lookup if `HOME` is not set.

Solution: unset `HOME`.

```
env -u HOME chroot --userspec=test path/to/subsystem/ /bin/bash
```